# How to return a widget from flutter plugin native code?

Tags: android, plugins, package, native, flutter

I am trying to learn flutter plugin development as I will need it anyway to act seriously with porting native SDKs.

The point is, I don't really know how to return an Android `Activity` as a `Widget` that could be placed in any `Column` or `Row` etc.

For now, all I did was to port Android's `Toast` functionality.

The flutter maps plugin seems to be little overcomplicated, while I am learning it I still look for a simpler example of how to convert native layouts into Flutter widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You can not return Android Activity as a Widget in flutter. Flutter plugins or flutter platform channels allow only basic datatypes or codecs between native, given [here](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/#codec).

You can still run an activity or display any widget by calling a method over platform channel, and once that activity is completed you can send result back to flutter code over the bridge using "MethodChannel.Result" object provided in method call.
like:

```
methodResult.success(data);
```

You can refer [ImagePicker plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/image_picker/image_picker/android) for details about how to run new Activity and add onActivityResult delegates to flutter registrar to handle and pass activity's result back to flutter.

Answer (score 0):

See [this guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-views#hybrid-composition) for hosting native Android and iOS views in your Flutter app. For example, if you need to host a view from a native Android or iOS SDK in your flutter app.